# C# Impersonation of an AD user

Tags: c#, impersonation

Here's a scenario I need some help with:

Client passes files to a webservice, which stores them on a unique generated folder (just for that operation).
The webservice saves the information about that files (location, health, etc) in a database.
A windows service (running as system) checks that database frequently for changes to process the files.
The files will be stored in a seperate database (like a library) for later use.
This operation needs to be done via the user who uploaded the files to the webservice.
I tried impersonation without password by passing the token but I never got it to work.

Any chance to impersonate an active directory user without his password to start the operation as this specific user?

Comment: Thank goodness it doesn't work! Or any hacker or malicious admin could fake a user's identity. You should find a way of passing the user's identity without requiring the password. Social app APIs do this by issuing a user-specific token that expires after some time.

Comment: Well, impersonation *does* work in limited circumstances, because there is a legitimate need for server applications running under administrative credentials to perform actions that need to be validated (by the OS) against the permissions that the user actually has. Obviously, impersonation is a restricted privilege, and note that administrators can *always* "fake a user's identity" -- they have every tool available to them to do so.

Comment: Hmm... why does it have to be the actual user account that does the file operation? Usually we have the server do this, and record the AD account that made the operation request to an audit log of some sort. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish here, seems a bit odd.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos because there is no API on server side that allows authentification via social apps. Beside that the network is "militarized zone", so no access to the internet.

Comment: @code4life
It's for the client on the server. It comes with an interface I have to call via the service that needs authentification from specific users.
This is mostly for records so you can see what every user did on their clients.
Sadly there are only 2 methods for authentification on the interface: via Windows Authentification or username and password.

Comment: @Thyrador: one word - argh!

Comment: @code4life: Well, this was not my decision.  ;)

Comment: @Thyrador: yeah, understood, which was the reason for the "argh!"...  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This almost certainly cannot work using impersonation, and the reason is that impersonation requires end-to-end support across every single function to achieve a result. In this case, that means that the entire connection stack to the database needs to support impersonation, and this is almost certainly not the case. [Raymond Chen has a nice article on impersonation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/28/10217445.aspx) that explains the trouble.

SQL Server (if that is your server) supports a form of impersonation itself through `EXECUTE AS`, but I don't recommend doing this with dynamic credentials -- it sounds like a security nightmare. You're better off getting the user identity and passing this along to a stored procedure that handles the security checks without actually impersonating the user. This procedure, of course, should be callable by the service only.

Comment: Well, thanks for clarification. Thought there was a way to through all that security stuff.

Storage server can be SQL, MySQL and Oracle but managed by a client who needs to be authentificated by specific users.
That's why I came up with the idea to impersonate them "to do their work" asynchronly.

So the only way of doing this right will be to force the user to enter their password, encrypt them, pass them to the server, encrypt it and login with their credentials.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you can get the user to enter their password, you can simply logon as that user and launch a separate process to perform the work as that user -- this sidesteps any issues with impersonation.

Comment: Yeah, seems to be the only way to achieve that. It was just because my company wanted the "easy way" (without having the user doing "anything").
I'll never get that philosophy but the don't pay me for thinking about that.

Comment: If I was a user, I would get mighty annoyed at an application that requires me to enter my password every time I use it even though I'm not doing anything that requires special permissions like installing an application, so I certainly support the idea of building a solution that doesn't require that -- and yeah, that's why they pay you. :-)